# Flutter Mapbox clickable cluster annotations

Tags: flutter, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am trying to use Flutter [mapbox_gl](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl) package to display clustered data, support for this functionnality has been added recently as showed in this [example](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/example/lib/sources.dart).

When the user zooms in, I would like to make symbols clickable, I have followed this example of [clickable annotations](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/example/lib/click_annotations.dart) but it seems not working, basically what I did is exactly combining the two examples: adding cluster layers (symbols and circles) using the map controller through `onStyleLoadedCallback` property, then adding on-click callbacks in my  `onMapCreated` property (using `onSymbolTapped` & `onCircleTapped` methods). Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For the clickable annotations from a source, as they come from a GeojsonSource, you must use `onFeatureTapped`. This will give you 3 data : the id (defined in the source), the point (coordinate on the screen) and the latlng (position on the map).

This allows you to set a generic callback for both the features in the source and the clusters made with it.

The package currently does not support having more data returned in the callbacks.